# Can I override inline !important?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

If you have

```
<div style="display: none !important;"></div>
```

Is there a way to override that in the style sheet to make it displayed?

Preferably using something similar to this:

```
div { display: block !important; }
```

Comment: For overriding the `display: block !important`, `visibility: hidden;` will work. Anyway, not related to the question. But thought to share.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Let me begin by saying that *generally inline styles **can** be overridden*:

```css
.override {color:red !important;}
```

```html
<p style="color:blue;">I will be blue</p>
<p style="color:blue;" class="override">But I will be red</p>
```

This behavior is described [in W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules), where it is stated that `!important` declarations do not alter the specificity, but rather *take precedence* over "normal" declarations.

That being said, when conflicting rules both have the `!important` flag, specificity dictates that an inline rule is applied - meaning that for OP's scenario, there's no way to override an *inline* `!important`.

Comment: The OP clearly states  `inline !important` - please read properly! Nonetheless +1 for good answer.

Comment: @Christoph: but the answers just as clearly state "you can not override inline CSS", "inline has higher precedence"... That's wrong hence the original phrasing of my answer. I don't expect everyone to edit their answers to correct the mistake

Comment: Your answer says nothing about overriding `!important` inline styles. The question asks about overriding `!important` inline styles only.

Comment: @BoltClock: well, I do say there's no way to override an inline important (except w/user styles, but that's outside of OP's control). I'm concerned about the phrasing used in other answers suggesting that a vanilla inline rule cannot be overridden.

Comment: The last sentece is not quite correct. If the users browser has a custom css rule with !important that overrides even inline css rules with !important.

So the only way is to have a custom css rule in the browser with !important for that specific (type of) element.

Answer (score 33):

You cannot override inline CSS if it has `!important`. It has higher precedence than the style in your external CSS file.

However, if you want it to change some actions later on, you can use a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: Cannot use javascript, it's for emails.

Answer (score 10):

You can not override inline CSS having `!important`, because it has higher precedence, but, using JavaScript, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, so I don't need to inline important because whatever I inline will take over the classes. Good!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot override inline style having `!important`. First preference is inline style.

For eg: we have a class

```
.styleT{float:left;padding-left:4px;width:90px;}
```

and in jsp

```
<div class="styleT" id="inputT" style="padding-left:0px;">
```

here doesn't take the `padding-left:4px;` .It takes class `styleT` except the padding-left:4px;.
There will be `padding-left:0px;`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple jQuery solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div').css('display','block');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see this example! There are several rules for CSS selector. The strongest selector is inline (if same level with/without !important). Next ones: id, class, etc. So if a tag is already stylized by inline css with !important, you just have a way: use Javascript to change.

```js
var pid = document.getElementById('pid');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  pid.style.color = '';
});
```

```css
p{color:violet !important;}

*{color:blue !important;}

html *{color:brown !important;}

html p{color:lighblue !important;}

.pclass{color:yellow !important;}

#pid{color:green !important;}
```

```html
<p class="pclass" id="pid" style="color:red !important;">
Hello, stylize for me !
</p>

<button id='button'>Change color by JS</button>
```

As you see, the style by inline css was removed and the id is the strongest selector now !

Answer (score 0):

Precedence rules when two CSS properties apply to the same node:

- `!important` beats not-`!important`.  If equally !important, ...
- `style` attribute beats css in a file.  If both are in css files...
- an ID in the CSS selector beats no ID.  And more IDs beat less. (and you thought there was no reason for two IDs in a selector.)  If same ID count...
- Classes, or attributes like `[name]` in the selector, count them; more beats less.  If all those are the same...
- tag names like `span` or `input`, more beats less.

So you see the inline `!important` is the highest precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override it in a style sheet. JS will help in your case. For example, the `querySelector()` method. Place the script line below the block `div`.

```html
<div style="display: none !important;">Your div display block</div>

<script>
document.querySelector('[style="display: none !important;"]').style.display="block";
</script>
```