# How do you prevent inline CSS link "color" from canceling out CSS stylesheet link "hover"?

Tags: css, colors, hover, toggle, inline-styles

I want my links*** to change color when clicked, but also change color when hovered over.

I got a javascript function to change the color when clicked, but it requires inline CSS which is keeping my style sheet's hover from working.

Is there a way to have the inline CSS and CSS stylesheet not cancel out? Or is there another way to change the color of the link when clicked that wont cancel out the hover color?

***(These links are being used to show a hidden div using javascript)

**script:**

```
function toggle_link(select){
var color = select.style.color;
select.style.color = (color == "white" ? "yellow" : "white");
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="gdtitle">
<a class="port" href="#" onclick="toggle('gdhide');toggle_link(this);" style="color:white">Graphic Design</a>
</div>
```

**css style sheet**

```
a.port{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
a.port:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: So you want it to toggle white/yellow on every click, but always hover yellow. So if it's currently yellow, you want it to stay yellow on hover. Right?

Comment: Right. When it toggles white/yellow it also toggles a hidden div. (I.E. white=hidden yellow=not hidden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `!important` [to override inline css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150684/can-i-override-inline-important/11151859#11151859)

Better yet, *don't* but alter the behaviour of your `toggle_link` - would you rather add a class to the element and style it instead?

Comment: I added !important to the hover and that worked.
(color: yellow !imporant;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:link`, `:visited`, and `:active` pseudo-classes on the `<a>`.

CSS:

```css
a.port, a.port:link, a.port:visited, a.port:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I'm under impression that the `toggle_link` functionality is different from what would be accomplished by `:active`

Comment: Have to agree with @ThinkingStiff; the :active pseudo-class is a better solution than using a click event handler just to change the style. It is also more usable, as :active works with keyboard navigation, and a click handler only works for mouse clicks

Comment: When you click the link it is toggling open a hidden div. When this div is open I want the link to change to yellow. The :active pseudo-class isn't doing that.