# Kendo UI MVC grid Popup postion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

How do I change the location for the popup for creating a new record? I can change the width by using javascript and setting e.container.width(1300). This causes the popup to position left:740. I try to over ride by setting DIV.k-window to 150px and the inline style overrides it. Does anyone know how to force the location of the popup?
TIA
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using this answer from Stackoverflow [Can I override inline !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150684/can-i-override-inline-important)
Thanks
Bruce