# Can I override !important?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

What I am trying is setting this CSS on element:

```
background: red !important;
```

But when I try to do this:

```
 background: yellow;
```

it still only shows the red and not the yellow for that one field as I would like it to be (I am not using external CSS).

What I am asking is how to override it, is it possible?

Comment: And that's why we don't use `!important` kids! You can override `!important` with `!important`.

Comment: with another !important, but use after the first one , but usually in 95% of the cases you can avoid using !important

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ans is **YES** `!important` can be overridden but you can not override `!important` by a normal declaration. It has to be higher specificity than all other  declarations.

However it can be overridden with a higher specificity `!important` declaration.

This code snippet in Firefox's parser will explain [how it works](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/layout/style/nsCSSDataBlock.cpp#576):

```
if (HasImportantBit(aPropID)) {
  // When parsing a declaration block, an !important declaration
  // is not overwritten by an ordinary declaration of the same
  // property later in the block.  However, CSSOM manipulations
  // come through here too, and in that case we do want to
  // overwrite the property.
  if (!aOverrideImportant) {
    aFromBlock.ClearLonghandProperty(aPropID);
    return PR_FALSE;
  }
  changed = PR_TRUE;
  ClearImportantBit(aPropID);
}
```

**Good read**

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

---

Here's an example to show how to override CSS

**HTML**

```
<div id="hola" class="hola"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
div { background-color: green !important; }
.hola{    background-color:red !important; }
#hola{    background-color:pink !important;}
```

and output will be

> [image]

Also we can not override inline `!important`

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo" class="demo" style="background-color:yellow !important;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { height: 100px; width: 100px; }
div { background-color: green !important; }
.demo{    background-color:red !important; }
#demo{    background-color:pink !important;}
```

the output is

> [image]

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: @teresko: +1, `!important` declarations do not alter the specificity, but rather *take precedence* over "normal" declarations

Comment: According to the articles linked this is not true. and I quote, "The !important value appended a CSS property value is an automatic win. It overrides even inline styles from the markup. ". - I'm just playing devils advocate - I will test this now. and NullPointer + articles are correct for Chrome + Windows at least. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/J7HyR/ see here.

Comment: Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources. and that firefox source code is looks fine as an official source and answer is ok and i understand now

Comment: i didnot knew that its written in c :)

Answer (score 15):

As described in [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules), `!important` declarations do not alter the specificity, but rather take precedence over "normal" declarations. Effectively, such declarations only "compete" between themselves - thus, you can override yours with another `!important` declaration of higher specificity:

```
/*
 these below are all higher-specificity selectors and, if both 
 rules are applicable to the same element, background colour
 will be set to "yellow":
 */
.some-class.some-other-class, div.some-class, #some-id {background: yellow !important;}
.some-class {background: red !important;}
```

There is also the declaration order to consider - a declaration further down in the CSS will take precedence over an earlier one if their selectors have the same specificity.

A case worth noting is when it clashes with an inline declaration. Counterintuitively (but fully in line with the spec), the `!important` value will come out on top! This means that if you have

```
<style>
  #secret-container {display:none !important;}
</style>
<script>
  $('#secret-container').show();//using jQuery etc.
</script>
<div id="secret-container">...</div>
```

the div in question will remain hidden! The only way to have an inline rule take precedence over an `!important` one is, well, by applying `!important` to it as well. I'll let you be the judge of how good a practice that is ಠ_ಠ

There's [no overriding inline `!important`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151859/1081234) though.

Answer (score 12):

`!important` will override `background: yellow;` Try to avoid using `!important`. Take a look at css specificity. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/