# Cursor not working in a:hover

Tags: css, hover, cursor

I am having an issue with some css. I am trying to set a custom cursor for when hovering over links. I am trying to with this code but nothing happens and it stays the pointer.

```
a {
    color: #99ccff;
    cursor: paw.cur;
}

a:hover {
    color: #71b2f4;
    cursor: paw.cur;
}
```

Even adding `!important` to the end of the a:hover one doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using: `cursor: paw.cur;` is **incorrect CSS syntax.**

You have to specify a URL if you want to use a *custom* image based cursor..

View the specs on cursor.. [**documentation here (mozilla developer**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

---

### Here is an example of a ***custom*** cursor..

```
a:hover {
    cursor:url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif), auto;
}
```

[**jsfiddle here - custom**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/5/)

---

### Here is an example of a ***default*** cursor..

```
a:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

[**jsfiddle here - defualt**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/9/)

---

I actually answered a question ***similar*** to this a while ago: [Using external images for CSS custom cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors/18551357#18551357)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this:

```
cursor: url('paw.cur');
```

or

```
cursor: url('paw.gif');
```

You need to use a URL if you want to use a custom cursor.

> [**Quoting from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)
>
> Formal syntax: [ [  [ ]?,]* [ auto | default | none | context-menu | help | pointer | progress | wait | cell | crosshair | text | vertical-text | alias | copy | move | no-drop | not-allowed | e-resize | n-resize | ne-resize | nw-resize | s-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | w-resize | ew-resize | ns-resize | nesw-resize | nwse-resize | col-resize | row-resize | all-scroll | zoom-in | zoom-out ] ]
>
> > `<uri>`
> > A url(…) or a comma separated list url(…), url(…), …, pointing to an image file. More than one  may be provided as fallback, in case some cursor image types are not supported. A non-URL fallback (one ore more of the other values) must be at the end of the fallback list. See Using URL values for the cursor property for more details.

And

> Even adding !important to the end of the a:hover one doesn't work.

### **Trust me `!important` isn't do magic** every where it just set highest priority

**Useful post**

- [Is !important bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13743671/2803260)
- [Can I override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14462840/2803260)