# Can I "stack" !important;?

Tags: css

I googled a little bit and I couldn't find the answer.

My question is: does stacking !important works in some way? Or can I achieve the same functionality in another way? **I'm aware that it's not a good practice**

Example, say I have:

```
.myOuterDiv
{
   margin-left: 5px !important; 
}

.myInnerDiv
{
   margin-left: 10px !important; 
}
```

It's obvious that the content of the inner div will have a margin of 10px, but can I add another important such as

```
.myOuterDiv
{
   margin-left: 5px !important !important; 
}
```

I wanna do exactly that, override the inner important so I can have a margin-left of 10. Can I do it like this or in some other way?

Comment: No, you can't.  This makes [part of my project](http://styliner.slaks.net/#limitations) impossible.

Comment: post your html, there should be a million other ways to style what you are trying to do without even using 1 !important

Comment: You can't override a style on a different element anyway, if we are to assume that `.myOuterDiv` and `.myInnerDiv` are in fact two different elements. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okay so can I do it in some other way?

Comment: Like I said it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @J McFee yes there are, the problem is that I don't have control over the inner css style. Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I override !important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462840/can-i-override-important)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot stack `!important`.. it doesn't work that way.

`!important` can be avoided a **majority** of the time, there are *usually* alternatives.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yeah the thing is that I can't do that because the content is inside an iframe and it's kind of crazy. I'll try to find the way using javascript. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The thing is that I don't have control neither of the inner css style neither the fact that it has important in it, because it's hardcoded inside a .dll . I believe that using css is a lost cause and I'll have to change the style manually using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override a CSS property by using a more specific selector.

If you have a rule being applied as `.myOutterDiv { some-property: some-value !important; }`, all you need to do is actually make yours have more weight. You can do that by doing, for example, `div.myOutterDiv { some-property: some-other-value !important; }`

Edit: You can read more details on **[CSS Specificity Value](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**