# Is there anyway to override the inline important?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Say, I'm using a plugin, component and there is inline-css applied with `!important`. Now how could I override that css.

Here's an example which would obviously not work as div is more specific but with given important in inline makes it more specific.

```
<div>
    <p style="color: red !important;">color is red</p>
</div>

div p{
    color: blue !important; /*I wanted to override but this won't work*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daAzr/)

Comment: Not in this instance. [It isn't possible to stack `!important`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323204/can-i-stack-important)

Comment: Generally, inline styling doesn't have `!important`.. is there a reason you tagged this with jQuery..?

Comment: I'm using djimage slider and couldn't find the inline-css. Any help would be great help for me.

Comment: You have to edit that inline styling. Usually inline styling has the priority than the CSS. Since this is marked as !important, it is the superior now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot change the HTML due to the use of a plugin, you can only use JS to get rid of it. Thankfully it's quite simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/daAzr/1/

```
$('div p[style]').attr('style', '');
```

(following your example.) Obviously make it a bit more specific for just the bits in that plugin you want to change.

Comment: 1+ But it's a little redundant to use `p[style]`, since you are targeting the style attribute anyways.

Comment: But can I remove just width and height property from that style instead of removing whole style attr?

Comment: Hmm, yes, but it's not as simple. You'd have to search inside the string using regex to pull out the bits you want.

Comment: I wanted to set the width: 100%; to that as there is width: [some]px.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` rule can not be override.

Instead try removing `!important` from inline then your css will work fine.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IMoMEleZ/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can not override inline CSS having !important, because it has higher precedence, but using Javasctip/Jquery tweaks you may achieve what you want.
you can use this:DEMO

Answer (score 0):

Its possible
Use Jquery for this purpose

```
$(function () {
    $('p')
        .attr('style', 'color: blue !important;')
});
```

demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/jjWJT/25/