# !important in css isn't working

Tags: html, css, html-table, rows

I'm trying to override the background of my rows in the table
This is what I did:

```
<tr style="background-color:#000099 !important;">
```

and this was the result:
http://onlinehandytools.com/blah.php?board=EDE&level=AL&subject=biology&year=2010
I've spent 2 hours on that, I've googled everywhere nothing seems to work
The only thing that have worked is

```
<style>
td{ background-color:#000099 !important;" }
</style>
```

But I don't want to do this, I will have different background colors of rows.
I tried to make seperate classes for each kind of row but td.classname didn't work either

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "But I don't want to do this, I will have different background colors of rows." -- Do you mean, you **want** alternating row colours, but you want **different** alternating row colours to what you have now?

Comment: Your answer maybe here:

Can I override inline !important?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11151859/2388392

Comment: @setek no, I don't mean alternating row colours, I mean changing the row color depending on the information in the row,I'm doing this in the php. so each <tr> will have its own background-color attribute

Comment: @etoxin no my answer wasn't there, I've already seen this quesiton when I was searching about it.

Comment: @user74670 so each row will its own color depending on information it has ? scrip based you mean ?

Comment: Could you apply a class to it instead of applying a `style=""` attribute? Then you could just do `tr.thiscolor td { background-color: #f00; }` with `<tr class="thiscolor">`

Comment: The question itself should contain enough code to reproduce the problem. This one doesn’t, since it does not even show any code that needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add this to your kindo css file , because kindo script will overwrite your css:

kindo.common.min.css:line # 9

```
.k-grid td
```

this is the css for the td just add your background color.

Edit:

Maybe this is what you are searching for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".k-grid td:contains('Jan')").css("background-color","#000099");});
```

[image]

this is how it looks

Comment: I will try this
so you want me to
.k-grid td.Jan{
color-background:yellow;
}
and
<td class="Jan">
right?

Comment: Jan is the session, I will have several of them,each one with a diff background color

Comment: @user74670 one do it via javascript ? or css ?

Comment: @user74670 just open this file :kindo.common.min.css , go to line 9 , and add the color you want to your td.

Comment: if you want to do it via a script , which prolly you wanna do , because no one gonna fill inline style for all these rules , then just do via jquery: $('.k-grid td').css("background-color","red") // or whatever color your prefer.

Comment: if you want to assign single color for each row , then just do it also via jquery , $('.k-grid td').each(function(){$(this).css("background-color","red")//or whatever color you prefer}) , make sure you do this after document loads.

Comment: I did this: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){$('.k-grid td').css("background-color","red");});
</script>
it didn't work :'(

Comment: oh wait, $(document).ready(function(){$('.k-grid td').css("background-color","#000099");}); this is working now 
but what i want to do is this: $('.k-grid td.Jan') but that didn't work

Comment: there is nothing called Jan would you please tell me what is jan ? is it a class ?

Comment: @user74670 do you mean the td with text jan within ?

Comment: if you mean that you want to color all cells with Jan text inside , you should do this , $(document).ready(function(){$(".k-grid td:contains('Jan')").css("background-color","#000099");});

Comment: looks like it works, thanks alot for your help, i will try this as soon as i have access to a computer, but i wanted to know why didnt my code work? when i made a class and called it Jan?

Comment: because your css selector was wrong if you wanna select class jan , just do it via .jan{} , glad to help you , please select as correct answer if it helps.

Comment: it works, but when I click on the header of the column it sorts and it cancels all the colors :D

Comment: you can add same function inside the sorting function then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51317/discussion-between-user74670-and-prollygeek)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add `!important` to inline css as it has the highest priority.

Just do this:

```
<tr style="background-color:#000099">
```

Comment: inline CSS does not have the highest priority. It has the highest *specificity*. It can be overridden by `!important` elsewhere, which has a higher priority within the *cascade*.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your html to this

```
<tr class="grayRow" > ... </tr> 
<tr > ... </tr>
```

and then just set your style in css file like this

```
tr{
    background-color: #fff; 
}

tr.grayRow{
    background-color: #ddd; 
}
```

It shout be worked.

If you will change style from your css file NEVER use !important; flag on element in your html.
like this

```
<tr style="background-color:#000099 !important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have check your alternative rows is added a class "k-alt" in `<tr>` with color #f5f5f5; Even you have `<tr style="background-color:#000099 !important;">` , it will override by the class, because HTML parse out 1st then only insert the class "k-alt" by function. I suggest that you using jquery remove the "k-alt" or replace the "k-alt" background color by jquery.( I have see ur webpage have install Jquery Libary)

**Replace the background**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".k-alt").css("background","#000099");
});
</script>
```

Or **Remove the background**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  if($("tr").hasClass('k-alt')){ 
      $("tr").removeClass('k-alt');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: the removing worked
but it doesn't add the css
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  if($("tr").hasClass('k-alt')){ 
      $("tr").removeClass('k-alt');
      $(".Jan").css("background-color","#000099");
  }

});
</script>

Comment: you want all the "Jan" row change the background to #000099?, I found that you row not have the class name call Jan.

Comment: Is that you want this code `$("tr:contains('Jan')").css("background-color",'#000099');` ?

Comment: i will try the last code u gave me as soon as i have access to a pc.