# How can I hide with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I have the below code which is in a document that I don't control. I only have the option to upload one custom CSS file for overrides. How can I accomplish this? It is to get rid of the vendor link on our site. I am good with CSS, but they have it set up tricky.

```
<div style="display:block !important;text-align: center !important; padding: 15px; visibility:visible !important; opacity:1 !important; 
    height:auto !important; width:auto !important; op:auto !important; bottom:auto!important; left:auto !important; right:auto !important;">
    <a href="http://vendorsite.com" target="_blank" style="display:inline !important; font-size: 11px !important; 
        visibility:visible !important; position:relative !important; opacity:1 !important; height:auto !important; width:auto !important; top:auto !important; bottom:auto!important; left:auto !important; right:auto !important;">
        powered by Vendor Site
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You may be out of luck with pure css. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150684/can-i-override-inline-important). But javascript can do it easily enough.

Comment: try 
`div {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    text-indent: -9999px;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, it is not possible with pure CSS, as the `!importants` already declared in the HTML would override any CSS, *unless* there is a parent object not displayed above, that you can override.

If the `!important` tags were not there, the following would work:

---

Does it have any parent elements? You don't have any attributes to mess with on the parent div, so if this code is this code alone, you can try:

```
div { display: none; }
```

But that's a terrible idea and will hide all `div`s.

To apply css, you either name a classname,

```
<div class='parent-div'></div>

.parent-div { display: none; }
```

An id attribute:

```
<div id='parent-div'></div>

#parent-div { display: none; }
```

Or any other attribute:

```
<div animal='dog'></div>

div[animal='dog'] {display: none;  }
```

You **could** hide the child `a` tag:

```
a[href="http://vendorsite.com"] { display: none;  }
```

Comment: None of these will work because it's inline and has `!important`. http://jsfiddle.net/XqV8h/

Comment: Shouldn't next !important override previously declared?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
div[style*="!important"] {
  max-height: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/fasid/11/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
div[style*="!important"] {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform:    scale(0);
  -ms-transform:     scale(0);
  -o-transform:      scale(0);
  transform:         scale(0);
}

/* And to make sure... */
div[style*="!important"] a {
  color: transparent;
}
```

The key is to find out which other attributes you can use to hide this element. Elements that have not been marked with `!important` on the html. Play around with `text-indent` for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, you don't have control over the code, nor have any selectors to use, and to make it worse there are a bunch of `!important` inline rules.

You could make it "vanish" though, the link will still be there but nobody will see it nor click on it, try something like this:

```
// Get the vendor's link
a[href="http://vendorsite.com"] {
  // Reset mouse cursor
  cursor: default;
  // Set color to match page background background
  color: white;
  // Remove pointer events to make it appear as plain text
  pointer-events: none;
  // Set background to match page background
  background: white;
}
// Set selection color to match page background color 
a[href="http://vendorsite.com"]::selection {
    background: white;
}
// Mozilla selector (optional)
a[href="http://vendorsite.com"]::-moz-selection {
    background: white;
}
```

Nasty but does the job. I've made a CodePen to show how it works: [Hide with CSS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdLln)

I hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: you could simply use javascript:  for the specified element, add the attribute 'display:none'

Comment: With JavaScript this could be done in a breeze. But the OP specified _CSS_ only, which is the reason why it makes this a tricky question.