# Force an element to use inline styles instead of !important styles from stylesheet

Tags: css

I have an element with inline styles, which are set with JavaScript:

```
<div class="foo" style="top: 30px;">
```

I am forced to use an *unchangeable* CSS file that contains styles to override the inline styles:

```
.foo { top: 0 !important; }
```

Is there a way to force the element to use the inline styles *instead* of the !important styles defined in the CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

Put `!important` on the inline style also:

```
<div class="foo" style="top: 30px !important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was well answered. [Here's the link to another stack question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151859/5914723)

> Let me begin by saying that generally inline styles can be overridden:

```
.override {color:red !important;}​

<p style="color:blue;">I will be blue</p>
<p style="color:blue;" class="override">But I will be red</p>
```

> This behavior is described in W3 specs, where it is stated that !important declarations do not alter the specificity, but rather take precedence over "normal" declarations.
>
> That being said, when conflicting rules both have the !important flag, specificity dictates that an inline rule is applied - meaning that for OP's scenario, there's no way to override an inline !important.