# Protect element from global css

Tags: javascript, html, css

My js is embedded on a third party website and it creates an `<iframe>` which contains a simple comments panel , but apparently on this specific website there is a CSS stylesheet which styles every `<iframe>` tag in the dom with the `!important` flag , so i can't change those css rules and the website dev team won't change this behaviour, there is another way to overcome this? can i change the `tagname` and still be an iframe? anything?

Comment: is it possible for you to post the URL and give a bit more description of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Speir the url is currently blocked for the world, but that's quite simple to explain , the main page has something like that : "iframe { height : 20px !important;}" so every iframe in the page will have "height:20px" and i can't change it

Comment: Why not just give your iframe a unique ID or class to overwrite the site CSS?

Comment: Can you show the styles you are trying to override

Comment: @Pete something like that : "iframe { height : 20px !important;}"

Comment: you can add an  inline style to the iframe with important too and that will take precedence - important is usually only used to override any inline styles, so an inline style with important should rule all

Comment: @Pete i know but for that i will need to change my code logic because you can't set the "!important" flag via the style property , i thought there might be an easy way out , like changing the iframe tag name but still be an iframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150684/can-i-override-inline-important surely adding a style attribute will be easier than hacking up some non iframe version

Comment: Also if it is your code on their site - surely it should be them fixing their code to make it work, not you tailoring your code otherwise what happens when the next user wants a different implementation again?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `all` property with the `initial` value to default the styles for that element.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all):

> The all CSS shorthand property sets all of an element's properties
>   (other than unicode-bidi and direction) to their initial or inherited
>   values, or to the values specified in another stylesheet origin.

A code example:

```
#div-to-reset-styles {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

Just target your specific `iframe` and you should be fine.

Comment: Won't work , the "!important" flag overrides everything

Comment: Using `!important` is almost always a bad practice but, since you can't change that page's code, you can add `!important` to this code. That way, you override the other `!important`. If your rules have more specificity, they will override the others.

Comment: yeah i know but i can't change this, and yes i can override the !important but i will need to change all my js logic because you can't set "!important" via the style property, i thought there might be another way like changing the tag name and still be an iframe

Comment: Couldn't you just add an id to the `iframe` and handle that?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Specificity is your friend here. From this [overview](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/):

1. Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers.
2. Specificity is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don’t apply to some elements, although you think they should.
3. Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy.
4. If two selectors apply to the same element, **the one with higher specificity wins.**
5. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector: inline styles, IDs, classes, attributes, and elements.
   ...

The part in bold means that you can add a class to your element(s) in question and override the more generic iframe css definition like that.

Comment: Won't work , the "!important" flag overrides everything