# how to override css in element.style

Tags: css

I have this style under element.style ( from a third party library)

the css is inside element.style

normally i just change the css by copying the class and adding my own css with !important , but in this scenario , what to put in my css class .

Comment: not sure if there is any cool way of doing this but overriding an existing class with the color and `!important` tag may seem like the option :-)

Comment: Maybe you can change the style using javascript. `$(".class-name").css({background: '....'})`. If there are several elements has this class name and that elements have different background then.. This method is not the correct way.

Comment: overriding css class normally works , but in this example  this is inside element.style, if i override .de-objectiveit-lnonline-theme-oit-client-base-tree-Css3TreeAppearance-Css3TreeStyle-joint , it doesnt work correctly , So i was thinking if i can use element.style  some how in my css class

Comment: A note (for the purposes of clarification): when you see `element.style` in your DOM Inspector, that _means_ the style is coming from the `style=""` attribute of the element. (ie. not from any stylesheet).

Comment: right , But how to change it..

Comment: Where is the image (from original unedited post)? The question is very unclear now. Low quality. May flag this as "Low quality".

Answer (score 0):

The first approach, specifying a css class with `!important` should do the job.

However, When the inline style has `!important` applied to it as well there is no way you can override it. Then javascript (jQuery eventually) comes in play.

Read this answer for further details: [Can I override inline !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150684/can-i-override-inline-important)

Comment: i tried adding the css in this css class   .de-objectiveit-lnonline-theme-oit-client-base-tree-Css3TreeAppearance-Css3TreeStyle-joint, but that put my css on every row , whereas this css is only for the main row(main branch of Tree), Thats why i was thinking , can i use this element.tyle thing somehow in my css class

Answer (score 0):

The white arrow seems to come from an image , so you will need to replace it with another image of green arrow.Overall you seem to be on correct path.

```
element.style {
  background: lightblue url("img_tree.gif") no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

```css
.i-am-a-rider-overrider {
  background: green url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png") no-repeat center !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red url(' https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png') no-repeat center; height: 300px; width: 300px; display:block; margin:20px;"></div>
<div style="background: red url(' https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png') no-repeat center; height: 300px; width: 300px; display:block; margin:20px;" class="i-am-a-rider-overrider"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but where to put this  element.style{ .. code in my css class. How do i tell which class this element.style belongs to ,If i just write element.style{background: green"} , it does not do anything

Comment: oh no the important should work fine. just replace the class name with the very long classname in your example

Comment: you have already figured 90% of it , use element.classname as you would do for anything else inside your css copy paste the backgrond property. THEN CHANGE THE URL TO THAT OF A GREEN ARROW.

Comment: you will need a green  arrow image with you.

Comment: I added the css in the class with my green arrow , But you see it puts the green arrow also on child rows (Which is not correct) , (see in the screenshot)

Comment: add #x-auto-420 before your current class, use use #x-auto-420 element.classname

Comment: does that help ?

Comment: #x-auto-420 element.de-objectiveit-lnonline-theme-oit-client-base-tree-Css3TreeAppearance-Css3TreeStyle-joint
{
 background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAARElEQVR42mNgGJ7AeA5DiuFcBhOyDTCczbDfaDbDe7INARnAMJvhP9mGwAwg2xBkA8gyhKoGUOQFigKRomikOCENLQAAV5M56410GSMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") 0px 0px no-repeat !important;
 
}

Comment: did it like this ,It remvoed all the arrows

Comment: #x-auto-420 div.de-objectiveit-lnonline-theme-oit-client-base-tree-Css3TreeAppearance-Css3TreeStyle-joint { background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAARElEQVR42mNgGJ7AeA5DiuFcBhOyDTCczbDfaDbDe7INARnAMJvhP9mGwAwg2xBkA8gyhKoGUOQFigKRomikOCENLQAAV5M56410GSMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") 0px 0px no-repeat !important; }

Comment: the element word is supposed to be replaced with the word div